# Amazon S3 java android resume upload?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Using the code i found here, [S3 File Upload Code Sample](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html) , i was wondering how to add pause a upload, and how to resume the download again. For starters uploadRequest.setFileOffset(long argument) seems to set the offset of the file that i am uploading. Is this correct. So if i say setFileOffset(2000) the file will begin uploading from the 2000 bytes from  the start o the file ?? Secondly how would i allow the user to pause an upload ? abortMultipartUpload in the S3Client will probably not allow us to resume the download again ?? Is there any sample code  anyone can share that pauses and resumes the file upload ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track, but I have found this specific code for android that seems to do exactly what you want.

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-simpl3r